# How high is the nail in the tree?

Tags: lateral-thinking

When Lenny was five years old, he hammered a nail into a tree near his house to mark his height. Fifteen years later at age 20, Lenny returned to see how much higher the nail was. 
If the tree grew by 5 inches each month, how much higher would the nail be?

I have provided a hint if you need one:

> Remember that trees "________", and you will know the answer.

Answer (score 19):

The nail will be

> zero

inches higher.  Because...

> Trees grow from the top.

Comment: Chances are he won't even find the nail because the tree grew around it in width.

Comment: With a hard-drive magnet he will have a mysterious way of hanging something on the tree!

Comment: @dotancohen Oh snap, brb putting a strong magnet onto a tree to blow my kids' minds in a few years.

Comment: tjbtech I'm upset with you! I was about to answer with this last night after I edited the question and my iPod ran out of battery D:

Comment: You have my most sincere sympathies.  I mean, here you are selflessly improving the content for others, and you get screwed.  Well, no good deed...  But I didn't realize people still used iPods.  I figured, with smart phones and all, all they're good for is nailing to a tree.  You oughta see my mesquite.  It's like a Christmas tree of Nano's spanning six generations.  (Hence, my knowledge of the answer going in.)

Comment: take a look at https://www.flickr.com/photos/juiceybrucey/85750194/ for one rather dramatic example

Answer (score 0):

Nail won't be there as trees do grow they they also expand ,so then the trunk will expand the nail won't be there as they expand inside out.

Comment: This question was already answered over a year ago.

Comment: Won't the nail technically still be there, just covered up?